# How would I create a Nested Default Dictionary in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an Apps Script, and I've been trying to implement a Default Dictionary. So far, I've been able to yoink a couple of things that didn't end up working, the first one was this:

```js
class DefaultDict {
  constructor(defaultInit) {
    return new Proxy({}, {
      get: (target, name) => name in target ?
        target[name] :
        (target[name] = typeof defaultInit === 'function' ?
          new defaultInit().valueOf() :
          defaultInit)
    })
  }
}
```

And while this works well enough for a flat Default Dictionary with say `let locationDict = new DefaultDict(Array)`, or maybe `new DefaultDict(Number)`, it kind of breaks with `new DefaultDict(DefaultDict(DefaultDict(Array)))`.

Specifically, the error I get is `TypeError: Class constructor DefaultDict cannot be invoked without 'new'`... and I'm not sure what that means... I was hoping that the `new` keyword that's inside of the class constructor definition would take care of invocations of class constructors...

So I managed to find a workaround to fix it that seemed to make things rosy by turning it into a function instead of a class:

```js
function DefaultDict (defaultInit) {
  const handler = {
    get: (target, name) => name in target ?
      target[name] :
      (target[name] = typeof defaultInit === 'function' ?
        new defaultInit().valueOf() :
        defaultInit)
  }
  return new Proxy({}, handler)
}
```

and I had thought it was working dandy with the `new DefaultDict(DefaultDict(DefaultDict(Array)))` (because there weren't any errors) until I actually ran it with some data. Without going too nitty gritty, let me see if I can simplify the use case:

```js
   const data = [["Welcome to El Mirage Sign", "El Mirage", "Arizona", "United States"],
                 ["Indian Roller Bird", "Austin", "Texas", "United States"],
                 ["Greenbrier Park Half-Court", "Austin", "Texas", "United States"],
                 ["Pink Dinosaur Playscape", "Austin", "Texas", "United States"]]
  const caption = 0
  const subregion = 1
  const region = 2
  const country = 3
  
  let locationDict = new DefaultDict(DefaultDict(DefaultDict(Array)))
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    const caption = data[i][0]
    const subregion = data[i][1]
    const region = data[i][2]
    const country = data[i][3]
    locationDict[country][region][subregion].push(caption)
  }

  console.log(locationDict)
```

So here, I got this console value verbatim:

```js
{ 'United States': 
   { Arizona: { 'El Mirage': [Object], Austin: [Object], inspect: [] },
     Texas: { 'El Mirage': [Object], Austin: [Object], inspect: [] },
     inspect: { 'El Mirage': [Object], Austin: [Object], inspect: [] } },
  inspect: 
   { Arizona: { 'El Mirage': [Object], Austin: [Object], inspect: [] },
     Texas: { 'El Mirage': [Object], Austin: [Object], inspect: [] },
     inspect: { 'El Mirage': [Object], Austin: [Object], inspect: [] } } }
```

and I imagined a lot of stuff was just header stuff, in the debugger I can actually inspect the `Array` objects as well, and the arrays were actually correct, but the problem lies in the cities, or the "subregions" as I called them. It seems that `Arizona` and `Texas` both share the same value object.

I expected something more like this:

```js
{
  'United States': 
  {
    Arizona:
    {
      'El Mirage': ["Welcome to El Mirage Sign"]
    },
    Texas:
    {
      Austin: ["Indian Roller Bird", "Greenbrier Park Half-Court", "Pink Dinosaur Playscape"]
    }
}
```

And so this is where I'm not sure where to go from here... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `new DefaultDict()` should be a function, not a value. So you need a function that returns a `DefaultDict` for the nested value.

You also should call it without `new`, since it might not be a class constructor function. This allows you to provide a function that returns an instance of a class, such as the nested `DefaultDict`.

While your proxy allows the argument to be an instance, that's not what you want in this case. A single instance will be created when you create the parent `DefaultDict`, and all elements will refer to that same instance.

```js
class DefaultDict {
  constructor(defaultInit) {
    return new Proxy({}, {
      get: (target, name) => name in target ?
        target[name] :
        (target[name] = typeof defaultInit === 'function' ?
          defaultInit().valueOf() :
          defaultInit)
    })
  }
}

let myDict = new DefaultDict(() => new DefaultDict(Number));

myDict.abc.x = 1;
myDict.abc.y = 2;
myDict.def.x = 3;
myDict.def.y = 4;

console.log(myDict.abc.x, myDict.abc.y, myDict.abc.z, myDict.def.x, myDict.def.y, myDict.def.z);
```

Comment: Ah! It works! Thanks so much! Albeit as I nest more `DefaultDicts` though, it gets a little hard to read. May I bother you with a little explanation as to why it is that I have to structure it like this? Is there a way for the constructor to accept class definitions such that it can create the instance at construction? That way everything doesn't have to be wrapped in a loose arrow function?

Comment: Not unless you define a specific class for the nested dictionary. You need a function  to pass a parameter to a constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very confused, I don't know what you mean by, "You need a function to pass a parameter to a constructor"... I'm also rereading your answer with fresh eyes and I'm understanding it a tiny bit more, I'm actually comprehending this: "The argument to new DefaultDict() should be a function, not a value." haha, but then my question is, "why does it need to be a function?" I think I'm missing some fundamentals of JS here...

Comment: It needs to be a function so you can create a new nested dictionary each time you need one. Otherwise they'll all be references to the same dictionary.

Comment: You could call `copy.deepcopy(defaultInit)` as a workaround, but not everything supports that. A function has full flexibility to do whatever is needed.